# How to schedule a function to run at a certain date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scheduled-tasks

I have a website that allows users to send themselves a message at a date they choose, but I have no idea how to send it at that specific time. I know there exist CronJobs, but here, I'm not doing anything recurring. It's a one-time event trigger that I need.

I first tried using the native `setTimeout` like this:

```
const dueTimestamp = ...; 
const timeLeft = dueTimestamp - Date().now(); 
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => sendMessage(message), timeLeft);
```

It works perfectly for short periods, however, I'm not sure if it is reliable for long periods such as years or even decades. Moreover, it doesn't offer much control because if I'd like to modify the   `dueDate` or the message's content, I'd have to stop the Timeout and start a new one.

**Is there any package, a library, or a service that allows you to run a NodeJS function at a scheduled time?** or do you have any solutions? I've heard of Google Cloud Schedule or Cronhooks, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could create a chon job that removes itself when it runs.

Comment: And how would I do that programmatically? Because here, the user will be choosing when the function would run.

Comment: You could run a script with CRON at regular intervals. The script could access a database with email addresses and date to send email. Then the script could send any emails that have date to send that is the same as the date now. With your method, I presume if you close down the browser no more emails will be sent as the script terminates? Just saw this: http://www.jimlynchcodes.com/blog/setting-up-an-ubuntu-server-for-running-nodejs-cron-jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by [user3425506](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425506/user3425506), I simply used a Cron job to fetch the messages from a database and to send the message of those whose timestamps have passed.

Dummy representation:

```
import { CronJob } from "cron";
import { fakeDB } from "./fakeDB";

const messages = fakeDB.messages;

const job = new CronJob("* * * * * *", () => {
  const currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();

  messages.forEach((message, index) => {
    if (message.timestamp > currentTimestamp) return;

    console.log(message.message);

    messages.splice(index, 1);
  });
});

job.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) library. for example :
you want to run a funcation at  5:30am on December 21, 2022.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const date = new Date(2022, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

Comment: The problem with that method is that I won't be able to modify a schedule once it has been set. I could store the job object in a hashmap, but that is not reliable. It would have been better if I could store the job object in a database, but that is not possible either.